# Trying to run this app with “npm start” and it won’t work. How do I make this app work?

Tags: npm-start

I am trying to get this app to work on my laptop. I am using npm start to start the application but it gives me errors. How do I get it to start? This is the code I am using. It is a clone of an app on GitHub.

https://github.com/adrianhajdin/project_medical_pager_chat.git

Comment: What errors do you receive? Did you run `npm install`?

Comment: PS C:\Users\elycm\OneDrive\Desktop\project_medical_pager_chat-master> npm start
PS C:\Users\elycm\OneDrive\Desktop\project_medical_pager_chat-master> npm start
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\elycm\OneDrive\Desktop\project_medical_pager_chat-master/package.json  
npm ERR! errno -4058-----------------------------------------------------------npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\elycm\OneDrive\Desktop\proje
ct_medical_pager_chat-master\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and put the errors there. They are very hard to read in comments, and comments can be deleted at any time for any reason.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, you're not running `npm install` in the right directory.

There is a `client` and a `server` folder. You need to `npm install` in both, and run both.

1. Download the ZIP file and extract
2. Go into the `server` folder and run `npm install && npm start`
3. Go into the `client` folder and run `npm install && npm start`
4. This will cause http://localhost:3000/ to open in your default browser which is the client application, which apparently connects to the server application.

Note: I had to change the server port from 5000 to 5001 for some reason. That change can be made in `server/index.js`. You may not have this probem.